# (Delphi) Is it possible to change a label to whats in a .html file?

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-xe7

Is it possible to change a Label caption to what is in a `.html` file? Lets say the `.html` file contains `1.0` in it. Can I make the Label retrieve that and change its `Caption` to that value?

Eg. `lbl1.caption := http://www.example.com/example.html;`

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: A label caption is just a string. Nothing special. Don't get bogged down in thinking that everything has to be done through the form designer, point and click. You've got a proper programming language to hand. Your question is really just, "how can I perform an HTTP GET and capture the result in a string". A question that has been asked hundreds of times already.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm still new to delphi and my school only teaches the basics of it. I don't really have anyone to teach me but i'll keep that in mind. Thx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TLabel` cannot load content for you, whether that is from a file or a remote URL. You have to write your own code to retrieve the content yourself, and then you can assign it to the `TLabel`.  For example:

```
// using the Indy TIdHTTP component...
lbl1.Caption := IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.example.com/example.html');
```